# Keras Model IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv("translator.csv")

x_train, x_test = dataset[["Afrikaans Woorde", "English Words"]]
y_train, y_test = dataset[["Total Letter Amount", "Incommon Letters"]]

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

x_test = np.array(x_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

model = tfk.models.Sequential()

input_layer = model.add(tfk.layers.Flatten())

hidden_layer1 = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
hidden_layer2 = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))

output_layer = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(1))

compiler = model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="spare_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
fitter = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

print(f"Percentage loss {val_loss * 100}%", f"Percentage accuracy {val_acc * 100}%")
```

**Error:**

```
IndexError: list index out of range
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5408/3773670894.py in <module>
     22 compiler = model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="spare_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
     23 
---> 24 fitter = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
     25 
     26 val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

**Question:**

I have tried everything, I am not sure what to do? I have, even converted the dataset to an numpy array, yet it still gives me the error.

This specific model is to see if I can build a Translator just from a couple of words.

Comment: mathematically, your model architecture outputs only 1s

Comment: @NicolasGervais So what is the solution for the output only being 1's.

Comment: @NicolasGervais And how does it contribute to the indexing error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with random input, your model architecture outputs 1, which means binary classification.

Working sample code

```
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


X_train = np.random.random((1512,18))
y_train = np.random.random((1512,1))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(32)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(
        buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)


model = tfk.models.Sequential()
input = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(15, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(18,)))
input_layer = model.add(tfk.layers.Flatten())

hidden_layer1 = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
hidden_layer2 = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))

output_layer = model.add(tfk.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
fitter = model.fit(train_data, epochs=5, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

**Output**

```
Epoch 1/5
48/48 [==============================] - 4s 5ms/step - loss: 5.9153e-08 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
48/48 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 5.9153e-08 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
48/48 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 5.9153e-08 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
48/48 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 5.9153e-08 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
48/48 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 5.9153e-08 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```